# Can I unregister a class as an `Iterator`?

Tags: python, iterator, abc

I've been handed code with a class that incorrectly subclasses the abstract base class `collections.Iterator`.  It doesn't follow the Iterator contract and this flawed inheritance relationship causes issues downstream.  Is there any way to **unregister** an abstract base class?

*Note*: I know that this is a strange situation.  Please avoid the compulsion to voice an opinion on Monkey Patching.

Comment: You can not inherit from that class.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are not to inherit from that class, provide your own, correct and proper `next` method, or provide an alternative iterator to be returned from the `__iter__` method.

There is no registration involved here other than that `isinstance(instance, collections.Iterator)` is `True`, and that returns `True` for two reasons:

1. your class inherits from the `collections.Iterator` class; it is a direct subclass.
2. your class has `__iter__` and `next` methods; any class implementing these two methods will register as a `collections.Iterator`.

The base `collections.Iterator` class provides an `abstractmethod` `next`, and a concrete `__iter__` method (it returns `self`). If your subclass does not implement their own version of `next` then creating instances of that class will not work; a `TypeError` is raised complaining that `next` is an abstract method.

If the class is not an iterator, then your first option is to alter the original class not to inherit fro `collections.Iterator`.

The next option is to provide a fixed `next()` method; it requires that your instance keeps state to help produce the next value each time it is called, or raise `StopIterator` if there are no more new values to produce.

Your third option is to return a proper iterator from the `__iter__` method instead. Instead of returning `self` you could return a *new* object that implements iteration over the instance.